# SQL for finding a value having rows of closest to half of all unique occurrences of another value?

Tags: mysql, sql

Table rows I'm using:

```
`factid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`segid` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`factid`,`segid`)
```

---

Here's the steps of what I'm trying to accomplish:

- I need the total number of unique `segid` values in the table.
- I need a single `factid` value.
- This `factid` value needs to have rows with many unique `segid` values.
- 'Many' being [closest to half](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592209/find-closest-numeric-value-in-database) the above total unique `segid` values.

I hope this explains what I'm trying to accomplish.  Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1
    facts.factid
  , facts.segids
  , segs.total_segids
FROM (
    SELECT factid
      , count(distinct segid) as segids
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY factid
  ) facts,
  (
    SELECT count(distinct segid) as total_segids
    FROM my_table
  ) segs
ORDER BY abs(facts.segids - (segs.total_segids / 2))
```

Comment: I didn't know about `count(distinct <col>)`.

Comment: Question: Does any use of `ORDER BY <col> DESC` need to be specified with the subqueries?

Comment: There is no need to worry about the order of data in the subqueries because that information is not used in the outer query.

Comment: ...and today I (re?)learned `GROUP BY <col>` alters how `count(<stuff>)` returns, too!