# SQL - Find the closest price to a given argument

Tags: mysql, sql, database, db2

I am trying to find the tuples which price is closest to a given parameter in SQL.
Forexample: the parameter price = 6 would return id 1 and 2. 
Parameter price = 20 would return id 3.

Table :

```
ID     PRICE
1      5
2      5
3      10

SELECT id 
FROM Table
WHERE table.price ?? 6
```

Any Ideas how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592209/find-closest-numeric-value-in-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID
FROM TableX
WHERE PRICE = @CheckPrice +
      ( SELECT MIN(ABS(PRICE - @CheckPrice))
        FROM TableX
      )
   OR PRICE = @CheckPrice -
      ( SELECT MIN(ABS(PRICE - @CheckPrice))
        FROM TableX
      )
```

or (probably better for performance):

```
SELECT ID
FROM 
    TableX
  CROSS JOIN
          ( SELECT 
                ( SELECT MIN(PRICE) - @CheckPrice
                  FROM TableX
                  WHERE PRICE >= @CheckPrice
                ) AS Pover 
              , ( SELECT @CheckPrice - MAX(PRICE)
                  FROM TableX
                  WHERE PRICE <= @CheckPrice
                ) AS Punder
            FROM dual
          ) AS tmp 
WHERE PRICE IN ( @CheckPrice + LEAST(Pover, Punder)
               , @CheckPrice - LEAST(Pover, Punder)
               )
```

Comment: This will only return rows if `Min(Abs(price - @CheckPrice))` happens to exactly match a price already in the database. In the example in the question, `Min(Abs(price -6))` evaluates to `1`, which does not appear in the `price` column and therefore will not return any rows.

Answer (score 2):

This query selects the closest price using the subquery, then returns all rows which match that price:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE price = ( --could also use "WHERE price in" here...
    SELECT TOP 1 price FROM Table
    GROUP BY price
    ORDER BY Min(Abs(price - ?)))
```

Comment: Nice. But if there are prices `5,5,7` and you check for `6`, the result will be either the IDs with price 5 or the IDs with price 7 (more or less randomly).

Comment: I agree that it excludes the case where prices are equidistant, but it will consistently return the higher price due to the `ORDER BY` - not randomly as you suggest.

Comment: The `ORDER BY` is done after the `ABS()` call, so the `TOP 1` will be a rather random choice, I insist.

Comment: @ypercube OK, I do see your reasoning but I just set this up (in SqlServer though, not MySql) and get the same consistent results no matter what order the records were inserted into the table or how many are above/below the parameter. I guess it's to do with default sort orders?

Comment: Probably. I can't check now in either.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, price
FROM thetable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
   FROM thetable t2
   WHERE abs (t2.price - 6) < abs (t1.price - 6)
   );
```

Comment: Thank you. Has been a long time since I used sql

Answer (score 0):

We are using UNION subquery to get closest prices for target price.
In each subquery we get absolute delta (diff between each model price and target price) and ORDER BY delta in the end. Works pretty fast and stable. Hope it helps ;)

```
SET @CheckPrice = 3910;

(
    SELECT
        m_id,
        m_name,
        m_auto_price,
        m_auto_discount,
        ABS(m_auto_price - @CheckPrice)AS delta
    FROM
        s_models
    WHERE
        m_auto_price >= @CheckPrice
    ORDER BY
        m_auto_price ASC
    LIMIT 10
)
UNION
    (
        SELECT
            m_id,
            m_name,
            m_auto_price,
            m_auto_discount,
            ABS(m_auto_price - @CheckPrice)AS delta
        FROM
            s_models
        WHERE
            m_auto_price <= @CheckPrice
        ORDER BY
            m_auto_price DESC
        LIMIT 10
    )
ORDER BY
    delta ASC,
    m_auto_price DESC,
    m_auto_discount DESC
```