# Closest numeric value - but always return lower value

Tags: database

My question is very similar to this: [Find closest numeric value in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592209/find-closest-numeric-value-in-database)

However, to take the example used in the link above, how could this code be modified so that the lowest matching value is returned.  So 1.6 would return 1.5, but also 1.8 would return 1.5?
Thanks in advance
Mark

Comment: I appreciate that you dont know how to do this, but asking how can someone elses code be modified without showing your own code is kind of like asking people to write code for you.  Rather than link to another problem and ask for another answer, it would be better to describe your issue and show what you have done to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but how about

```
SELECT TOP 1 [property] FROM [table]
WHERE [valueColumn] < [input]
ORDER BY [input] - [valueColumn]
```

?

This way it will only take values lower than the input and order by their "distance" to the input.

Comment: You need to use `<=` otherwise the query will not get correct values in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code - based on `ASC and TOP(2) operators`

```
SELECT TOP (2) YourProperty  FROM [myTable] 
WHERE (condition)
ORDER BY YourProperty ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner version of @AsgerArentoft answer in my opinion:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [table]
WHERE [valueColumn] <= [input]
ORDER BY [valueColumn] desc
```

`<=` is important because if `valueColumn` has values 1,3,5 and input is 3, given `<` then the returned value would be 1.