# Assign multiple variables to conditions

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Currently I have three tables in a database which holds data about a patients illness, priority and waiting_ times. I want to assign a Patients priority and illness to an expected waiting time so for example: IF the patient has low priority AND non-urgent THEN expected_waiting_time = 3 hours.

Here are the tables which holds info about priority, illness and waiting times.

```
Priority Table
High
Moderate 
Low 

Illness Table
Critical 
Immediate 
Non-urgent

Expected_Waiting_time
0 - 10 (mins)
30 - 60
60 - 90
etc
```

Edited:

Example of output

```
PatientID  Illness      Priority   Expected waiting time 
 1         non-urgent    Low        3 hours 
 2         non-urgent     Low       3 hours 
 3         Critical       High      0
 4         Immediate      Moderate  1-2 hours
```

Comment: And, what have you tried?

Comment: Currently, I have a table outputting the patients info such as name, illness, disease etc but I dont know how to assign their illness and priority to a expected waiting time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table that links the **wait** with **illness** and **priority**. Then just select for 'wait' based on the values of the other two.

> select wait from wait_table where illness = <value> and priority = <value>;

The table would have all the unique combinations of **illness** and **priority** assigned to appropriate values of **wait**.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67e1c/2/0) is a fiddle. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Wouldn't this result in a lot of repeating data?

Comment: I currently have a priority_time table with illness, priority, expected_time, will I link this table to the three tables?

Comment: I want illness "non-urgent", priority "low" to be assigned to expected waiting time "3 hours". Is that possible?

Comment: Sure - but use numeric instead text for lookups. You can join to add text later. 'select wait from waits where pri = 3 (low) and illness = 3(minor);

Answer (score 0):

---

### Your Database

---

Let's begin at the beginning. Your tables are all the backend data you will need to successfully compute, and store, a client's waiting time.

**Your priority Table**

You have a `priority` table with one value in it. That's the first alarm. If it only has one value, is it not better as a field of another table? Perhaps combining this with a patient's details, means that with just the client's details, you can access all of their information. Perhaps something like:

```
Client Table
ClientID    ClientName    ClientPriority
```

This means, with the client's name, you can deduce their priority.

**The illness Table**

```
Illness Table  
IllnessID    IllnessName     IllnessLevel
```

This means that with the Client's illness, you can get to their IllnessLevel.

**Your waiting time Table**

I guess this is fine as it is. Having the waiting times in a different table means that you can change them as and when you need to. What I would recommend though, is changing it, so it looks more like this. The numbers are arbitrary, you can change them as you want, depending on the values you use for priority and the severity of an illness.

```
Expected_Waiting_time
Waiting_Time    PatientScore
0 - 10 (mins)   10
30 - 60         5
60 - 90         1
```

---

### Your Programming Logic

---

**Getting the necessary information**

Now, you need to take the patients details, and their condition. So let's say the client gives you their Name, or ID. Usually, at a doctors, you provide some sort of membership card and they get your details from that, so requesting an ID is a perfectly normal practice.

```
Client Inputs: ID 1
Client Illness: A Cold
```

From the client's ID, you make a call to the database, using some SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE ClientID=:ID
```

Notice here I've used a prepared statement. IF you don't know what these are, then you need to read up on them [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Once you have requested the Client's details, you have their priority. Next, you move onto their illness.

```
SELECT * FROM Illness WHERE IllnessID = :IllnessID
```

Once again, using a simple SQL statement, we have all the details about the illness.

**Performing the calculation**

In this section, you need to do something with the values you've got, to compute a score. For example, say 10 is a high patient priority, and the patient presents a `Critical` illness, then you might say they have a score of 20.

Simply Query the database, for the nearest value to 20. If you're not sure how to do this, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592209/find-closest-numeric-value-in-database) for some help.

And voila, you have your waiting times.

Answer (score 0):

My first observation is that your data points do not seem to make sense. If someone is Critical, then they are by definition High Priority and if they are Non-urgent then they will be Low Priority. Your tables seem to repeat the same information in a different way.

Also, you cannot get an absolute waiting time of "3 hours" from a set of data that says "60 to 90" minutes. You would have to end up with a range.

However, if we suppose that there can be such a thing as a Critical Low priority or a non-urgent high one then:

You need a table that relates Priority and/or Illness to a waiting time. You haven't given examples to show whether they are accumulative or whether they are distinct based on pairings. If the former then just add a time column in each of the Illness and Priority tables and you can add the values together. If the latter then build a table that has all possible combinations of Illness and priority and join to it.