# How to define which number from DATABASE is near (round) to getting number?

Tags: php, sql, rounding

I have an SQL TABLE like below. So on PHP page I enter the temp 44 or 43 and the number 1 or 2. For example I have entered the number: 2  and the temp :44...Php calcullates from formula (how it calcullates I think write about it is not important) and gets the number like 46.5777. So this number is not on DATABASE. I have to define which number from DATABASE is near (round) to 46.5777? How can I define it and show it?

```
num  temp   decimal

1    43     44.5760
2    44     47.0827
2    43     45.9396
3    44     48.5177
3    43     47.3053
```

Comment: how near ?? 46/47 ??? which one ?

Comment: @swapnesh, look I got the number 46.5777 and this number is round to 45.9396 and 47.0827 from database. But the number 47.0827 rounder to 46.5777 than 45.9396. So, I have to get the number 47.0827 on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Find closest numeric value in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592209/find-closest-numeric-value-in-database) - same problem.
In your example query will be `SELECT * FROM table WHERE num = 2 AND temp = 44 ORDER BY ABS(decimal - 46.5777) LIMIT 1;`. It should return the nearest value of 46.5777.