# Coldfusion query database to get the closest number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, coldfusion

im trying to solve an annoying query issue.

```
<cfset url.qty = "61000">
<cfset url.pages = "16">
<cfquery name="getCosts" datasource="#request.DSN#">
        SELECT ID, publication,pages,quantity, cover, cost, run_ons,run_backs, stock
        FROM calculator_data
        WHERE publication = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#url.publication#">
            <cfif url.qty IS NOT "">
            AND quantity = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.qty#">
            </cfif>
            <cfif url.pages IS NOT "">
            AND pages = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.pages#">
            </cfif>
        </cfquery>
```

What I am trying to do is pass in an argument of say

61000 and then retrieve the closest value to that so i can do some additional calculations via coldfusion.

I have ranges in the database that exist every 10,000 or so, so when I query using the above code all i get back is an empty query object.

So ideally if i query it to be
61,000 I wish to get back 60,000 so then i can use it as my base for additional calculations

Any ideas on how i can get the closest number to the value im querying against?

thanks in advance

Comment: Searching for "sql server find record closest to number" turned up this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/592230/104223

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about ColdFusion, but I think this should work. I am not able to understand with which column 61000 should be matched. So I have taken **qty** as a sample column name. Just take your real column instead of **qty**

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [calculator_data] 
Where qty < 61000
ORDER BY qty Desc
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, as it turns out i did exactly this a few minutes after posting my question =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<cfset url.qty = "61000">
<cfset url.pages = "16">
<cfquery name="getCosts" datasource="#request.DSN#">
    SELECT ID, publication,pages,quantity, cover, cost, run_ons,run_backs, stock
    FROM calculator_data
    WHERE publication = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#url.publication#">
        <cfif url.qty IS NOT "">
        AND quantity < <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.qty#">
        </cfif>
        <cfif url.pages IS NOT "">
        AND pages = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.pages#">
        </cfif>
    </cfquery>
```

The following line has been changed:

```
AND quantity < <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.qty#">
```