# Find a record with a key closest to a give value

Tags: sql

I have a two column table currently, with the columns 'probability' and 'age'. I have a given probability, and I need to search the table and return the age related to the closest probability. It's already in ascending order next to age, for example:

```
20  0.01050
21  0.02199
22  0.03155
23  0.04710
```

The only thing I can think of doing right now is returning all ages with probabilities greater than the given probability, and taking the first one.

```
select age from mydb.mytest
    where probability > givenProbability;
```

I'm sure there is a better approach to this than doing that, so I'm wondering what that would be.

Comment: You'd want to get a MIN of the ABS of the difference between the table value and the target value.

Comment: Which type of database please? MySQL, SQL Server, etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find closest numeric value in database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592209/find-closest-numeric-value-in-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytest
ORDER BY ABS( .0750 - probability )
LIMIT 1
```

Should return the top 1 closest value, based on a sorted list of the Absolute value of the Difference between Probability and givenProbability.

Comment: I'm not strong in MySQL. That error may be resolved by simply adding a semicolon to the end of the statement.

Comment: When I use this, I get an error on the 1, stating "syntax error, unexpected NUM, expecting END_OF_INPUT or ';' " even when I have a semi colon at the end

Comment: I found the appropriate syntax for "TOP 1", which is actually "LIMIT 1"

Answer (score 0):

Different solutions will work for different DBMS. This one works in DB2 and is standard sql:

```
select age 
from (
    select age
         , row_number() over (order by abs(probability - givenProbability)) as rn
    from mydb.mytest
)
where rn = 1
```