# Closest location based on Lat/Lng from database

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps-api-3, linq-to-sql

I have a list of Longitude and Latitude values in a database which i have obtained using Google Maps.

Within my ASP .Net site when a customer searches for an address and it doesnt exist in the database, i would like them to see the most closest location based on the values i have in my database.

My thought is when the customer enters the address i would do a lookup for the Lat and Lng values and then i need to compare them with the values i have in my database.

I know how to obtain the Lat/Lng but I dont know how to work out the next closest location based on Lat/Lng from the values in my database? Any other alternatives?

I've read up on Google maps but the closest i get is documentation to give me the nearest school, transport etc etc but not for the stores im holding in my database.

Comment: Assuming the Lat and Lng are separate columns you could do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592209/find-closest-numeric-value-in-database)

Comment: You need an implementation of the Nearest Neighbor search https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search