# How to select data that approaches to a value but doesn't need to be the exact value in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to make a query using Select in SQL where I have to show which field approaches closer to the number PI (3,141592...). How could I do that?

```
select * from Table where --????;
```

Comment: How close to the number?  1.000.000 is close to PI compared to 1.000.000.000.  Some more clarity around the need would be useful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find closest numeric value in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592209/find-closest-numeric-value-in-database)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL and PostgreSQL you can order your results by `ABS(col - 3.141592)` and use `LIMIT 1` to get the closest value e.g.

```
SELECT col
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY ABS(col - 3.141592)
LIMIT 1
```

For SQL Server, use `TOP 1 col` and remove `LIMIT 1`; for ANSI SQL you can use `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW` in place of `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: And `FETCH FIRTST` is the ANSI SQL way, supported by newer versions of SQL Server, Oracle, Postgresql etc.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has a convenient function [`pi()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html) so you don't need to hard-code the value.  So:

```
select t.*
from Table t
order by abs(t.col - pi())
limit 1;
```