# How to get closest value from oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as shown below and column A datatype is `Varchar2`, and suppose if i enter `8200.11` as input, i should get `8200.13` ,which is the closest value.How will i get it in oracle ?

```
A
8200.13
7300.46
8100.98
8200.01
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592209/find-closest-numeric-value-in-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo setup:

```
create table demo (a) as 
select column_value
from   table(sys.ora_mining_number_nt(8200.13, 7300.46, 8100.98, 8200.01));
```

Test:

```
select min(a)
       keep (dense_rank first
             order by abs(a - 8200.11)) as closest
from   demo;

   CLOSEST
----------
   8200.13

1 row selected.
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c32312/1)

The `first` function returns the first value of *x* in order of *y*. (There is also a corresponding `last` function.) [More details](http://sql.standout-dev.com/2018/09/the-first-and-last-functions-in-oracle-sql/)

If the column is a `varchar2` (why?) then the implicit conversion to number should work unless the column contains unexpected values. From 12.2 onwards you could avoid conversion errors with:

```
select min(a)
       keep (dense_rank first
             order by abs(to_number(a default null on conversion error) - 8200.11)) as closest
from   demo;
```

Comment: The answer is of course correct, but the explanation of the `first` function is not. `first` only refers to "y" - it takes the "first" values of "y". Which value of "x" is chosen does not depend on the `first` (or `last`) function, but on the embedded aggregate function - you chose `min`. (`first` may also return the **sum**, or the **average**, of "x" - nothing to do with its first or last value or any other specific value.)

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle 12C, you would do:

```
select a
from t
where a is not null
order by abs(to_number(a) - 8200.11)
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Although the `keep` syntax is fine, in earlier versions this would probably be written with a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select a
      from t
      where a is not null
      order by abs(to_number(a) - 8200.11)
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

You should not be storing numeric values as strings.